# Attempting to write jQuery Ajax method that posts contact form data to a PHP email script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Can anyone review my code please and tell me why the email is not sending? I'm attempting to write a jQuery Ajax method that posts contact form data to a PHP email script.

Here is the body of the contact form page:

```
<body>
    <?php require 'Includes/Header.php' ?>
<div id="container1">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1> 
    <form id="form" onSubmit="return validate(this);" method="post" action="customerMsg2.php" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" autofocus></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Email" id="Email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Leave a message: </td>
            <td><textarea name="Message" id="Message"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" id="sendEmail" value="Send Email"></td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
    </table>
    </form>
    <div id="ajax-message"></div>
</div>
<div id="container2">
    <ul id="slideshow">
        <li id="services"><h2>Make a Donation!</h2><br>
            Our pets need lots of love and attention while they wait for new homes.  Why not give today?<br><input type="button" value="Donate"></li>
        <li id="services"><h2>Check Out Our Podcast!</h2><br>
            Tune in weekly as Josh gives his unique perspective on pet-ownership and dutifully regulated capitalism.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <script src="slideshow.js"></script>
    <script src="ajaxsubmit.js"></script>
    <?php require 'Includes/Footer.php' ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the jQuery, ajax code (ajaxsubmit.js):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $form = $('#form');
    var ajaxmessage = $('#ajax-message');

    $form.submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: serializedData
        })
            .done(function (response) {
                $(ajaxmessage).removeClass('error');
                $(ajaxmessage).addClass('success');
                $(ajaxmessage).text(response);

                $('#FirstName').val('');
                $('#LastName').val('');
                $('#Email').val('');
                $('#Message').val('');
            })
            .fail(function (data) {
                $(ajaxmessage).removeClass('success');
                $(ajaxmessage).addClass('error');
                if (data.responseText !== '') {
                    $(ajaxmessage).text(data.responseText);
                } else {
                    $(ajaxmessage).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
                }
            });
    });
});
```

and here is the PHP script:

```
<?php 

        ini_set('SMTP', 'smtp.gmail.com');
        $to = '(i would put my email address here)';
        $firstname = strip_tags(trim($_POST["FirstName"]));
        $lastname = strip_tags(trim($_POST["LastName"]));
        $message = trim($_POST["Message"]);    
        $from = trim($_POST['Email']);
        $subject = "New contact from $firstname $lastname";


        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $from))
        {
            echo "Message sent.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Message not sent.";
        }

?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from php doc:

```
`<?php
   $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
  $subject = 'the subject';
  $message = 'hello';
  $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Your header info is not correct. 
Bye

Answer (score 0):

I did not check all your code but the PHP script has several problems:

First the mail function is defined as follows:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

You can't just put an email address string as `$additional_headers`.

For example:

```
$header = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Further I guess that you can't send emails with a different from header as your email address over the gmail server. Normally your hosting provider has already configured the needed settings for sending emails with the php mail function.

Comment: Please bear with me, I am still working on my certification and am very new at this.  You're telling me to change: $from = trim($_POST['Email']);                                                                                                           to: $header = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
and include $header in the mail function?

Comment: No, change from

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $from))

to
$header = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header))

And remove 
ini_set('SMTP', 'smtp.gmail.com');

So that the email will be sent over the smtp server configured by your hosting provider until you are shure that it works over smtp.gmail.com.